# Understanding the :not selector css

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my head around the not selector is css.  I'm trying to hide a div called "InfoRow" if the page doesn't have a class of 'home'

My first stab at this:

```
:not(body.home #InfoRow)  {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: `The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: `body:not(.home) #InfoRow  { }` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

> The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

> :not(.foo) will match anything that isn't .foo, including `<html>` and `<body>`

---

As the class `.home` would be set on the `<body>` tag, and `#InfoRow` is a child of `<body>`, you'd have to write it like this:

```
body:not(.home) #InfoRow {
    display: none;
}
```